# ApiException: 907122036: no right

Tags: huawei-mobile-services

I'm trying to create a special version of my app for Huawei App Gallery, this means replacing Firebase Cloud Messaging with Huawei Push Kit.

My app's failing to obtain a token with this exception:

```
I HMSSDK_HmsClient: receive msg status_code:0, error_code800100000, api_name:push.gettoken, app_id:102999567|, pkg_name:org.kman.test1.huawei, session_id:*, transaction_id:102999567ttoken20201001165618936966550, resolution:null
E HMSSDK_HmsInstanceIdEx: TokenTask failed, ErrorCode: 800100000
E HMSSDK_AutoInit: Push init failed
E HMSSDK_AutoInit: com.huawei.hms.common.ApiException: 907122036: no right
E HMSSDK_AutoInit:       at com.huawei.hms.opendevice.a.a(ErrorEnum.java:272)
E HMSSDK_AutoInit:       at com.huawei.hms.opendevice.k.doExecute(GetTokenTask.java:58)
E HMSSDK_AutoInit:       at com.huawei.hms.opendevice.k.doExecute(GetTokenTask.java:34)
E HMSSDK_AutoInit:       at com.huawei.hms.common.internal.TaskApiCall.onResponse(TaskApiCall.java:190)
```

According to Huawei documentation, this error ("no right") means that Push Kit is not enabled for the project. However it is enabled, I just checked.

I ran into this with my main work project where I'm adding AG support and also same exact issue with a small test app.

Main work project App ID: 102982583
Package: org.kman.skymail.huawei

Small test project App ID: 102999567
Package: org.kman.test1.huawei

I have done all (it seems) the other steps: adding agconnect-services.json, enabling plugin 'com.huawei.agconnect', creating a special upload certificate, uploading an .aab, adding sha-256 hashes to Project configuration, adding push_kit_auto_init_enabled to the manifest, creating a subclass of HmsMessageService.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check whether HMS push kit is enabled properly like below image:

[image]

Comment: Darn! My devloper console looked different - until I expanded the window and then I saw the UI elements like in your screenshot. Enabled push kit *there* and now onNewToken is getting called! Funny thing, there already was a checkbox for "push kit" and it was enabled already, which is why I was confused.

Comment: HMS developer website is like a maze. You never know where you are :)

Answer (score 0):

Login to app gallery connect, go to **My Projects**. Select your project. Select **Manage API** , and enable push kit.
For details, please refer to [Enabling Services](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/distribution/app/agc-enable_service#enable-service).

Answer (score 0):

This error code means the service is not enabled in AppGallery Connect.

Please check whether you have enabled the Push Service.

- You can follow [the guide](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/service/josp/agc/index.html) below to check:

1. Sign in to [AppGallery Connect](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/service/josp/agc/index.html) and select My projects.
2. Find your project from the project list and click the app for which you need to enable a service on the project card.
3. Click the Manage APIs tab and toggle the switch for the service to be enabled.

For more information, see [docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/distribution/app/agc-enable_service#enable-service).